# [Google Calendar Events]: Javascript wont run, Tooltip not showing

Tags: javascript, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, google-calendar-api

Im using Wordpress as my CMS to launch a website.
I've installed the plugin: Google Calendar Events, for Wordpress and using it without any problems.
The styling and everything else is as it should be.

NOW!
I've recreated my theme in Wordpress because I wanted to implement the Bootstrap grid system to make it responsive.

The Google Calendar Event plugin and styles do show as it should, but my huge problem now is that the tooltip wont pop-up anymore on hover and I can't even click events to be externally redirected to Google Calendar and view the events there.

**Ive checked the console and found an error:**

```
function gce_tooltips(target_items){
    jQuery(target_items).each(function(){
        //Add qtip to all target items
        jQuery(this).qtip({
            content: jQuery(this).children('.gce-event-info'),
            position: { corner: { target: 'center', tooltip: 'bottomLeft' }, adjust: { screen: true } },
            hide: { fixed: true, delay: 100, effect: { length: 0 } },
            show: { solo: true, delay: 0, effect: { length: 0 } },
            style: { padding: "0", classes: { tooltip: 'gce-qtip', tip: 'gce-qtip-tip', title: 'gce-qtip-title', content: 'gce-qtip-content', active: 'gce-qtip-active' }, border: { width: 0 } }
        });
    });
}
```

**Error message reads:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function gce-script.js:33
(anonymous function) gce-script.js:33
m.extend.each jquery.min.js:2
m.fn.m.each jquery.min.js:2
gce_tooltips gce-script.js:31
(anonymous function) gce-script.js:44
b.extend.ready jquery.min.js?ver=3.9.2:29
u jquery.min.js?ver=3.9.2:37
```

**EDIT**

**I don't know how to interpet the console error, can someone please help?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's on line 33 of **gce-script.js**?

Comment: Line 33 is the line after the comment in the code block above "jQuery(this).qtip({"

I dont get how that isn't a funciton anymore. Does bootstraps js break it or something?

Comment: How have you added qtip to your theme?

Comment: Yes!
I see know that the order in request with <script> elements was wrong so it works.

Thanks for your time!